# Achieving a CSS border with gaps between certain spots

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to use something like the code snippet I've included. The problem with mine is that I can't actually cover up the gaps between the border without using transparency... that's an issue because I want this box to go over an image. Surely there's some better approach. Does anybody have any ideas?

Ideally, there's some way to actually omit those parts in the border without using transparency, so that they don't exist at all. I've been digging for a few hours and can't seem to find a solution. Does anybody have any ideas?

```css
div {
 background: transparent;
  color: transparent;
 padding: 2rem;
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 margin: 3em auto;
 border: dashed 2px #BEBEBE;
}

div::before,
div::after {
 position: absolute;
 background: white;
 content: '';
 z-index: 1;
}

div::before {
 width: 70px;
 left: calc(50% - 35px);
 height: calc(100%);
 top: -2px;
}

div::after {
 height: 35px;
 left: -2px;
 width: calc(100%);
 top: calc(50% - 15px);
}

div>* {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you include more of your html and, ideally, some kind of visual representing what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiple background to achive this like below:

```css
div.box {
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 3em auto;
  
  background:
  /* Top (two lines)*/
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #BEBEBE 0 4px,transparent 4px 8px) top left/40% 2px,
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #BEBEBE 0 4px,transparent 4px 8px) top right/40% 2px,
  /* Left (two lines)*/
    repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #BEBEBE 0 4px,transparent 4px 8px) top left/2px 40%,
    repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #BEBEBE 0 4px,transparent 4px 8px) bottom left/2px 40%,
    /* Bottom */
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,#BEBEBE 0 4px,transparent 4px 8px) bottom/100% 2px,
    /*Right*/
    repeating-linear-gradient(0deg,#BEBEBE 0 4px,transparent 4px 8px) right/2px 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

That you can optimize with CSS variables:

```css
div.box {
  --c:#BEBEBE; /* Color */
  --t:2px;     /* Thickness*/
  --d:4px;     /* length of dashes */
  --h:50px;    /* size of the hole*/

  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
  --g:var(--c) 0 var(--d),transparent var(--d) calc(2*var(--d));
  background:
    /* Top (two lines)*/
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg ,var(--g)) top left /calc(50% - var(--h)/2) var(--t),
    repeating-linear-gradient(-90deg,var(--g)) top right/calc(50% - var(--h)/2) var(--t),
    /* Left (two lines)*/
    repeating-linear-gradient(180deg,var(--g)) top    left/var(--t) calc(50% - var(--h)/2),
    repeating-linear-gradient(0deg  ,var(--g)) bottom left/var(--t) calc(50% - var(--h)/2),
    /* Bottom */
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,var(--g)) bottom/100% var(--t),
    /*Right*/
    repeating-linear-gradient(0deg ,var(--g)) right /var(--t) 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>

<div class="box" style="--c:red;--t:4px;--h:90px;--d:8px;">

</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible for the gaps to remain the same width as the screen size scales?

Comment: @dougdimmadome they will remain the same width since I am using pixel value.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible for this to work in IE11?

Comment: @dougdimmadome for IE you cannot use `calc()` and CSS variable, so you have to consider my first code and do manual adjustment of the values

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an SVG

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-dasharray: 5 5;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M5,5
           L40,5 
           M60,5 
           L95,5
           L95,95
           L5,95
           L5,60
           M5,40
           L5,5
           "
        
        />
  
</svg>
```